# EF Codefirst Migrations new database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm confused as to what to do in the situation I've gotten myself into.

I've recreated my database after an issue. When I run up my project, CodeFirst creates the database from my EF model. The site then works fine.

But as soon as I come to add a migration, it says I've got explicit migrations pending on my database. These pending migrations are ALL existing migrations.

It appears that my DB has been created with the most recent model. But without any model/revision data attached.

How do I go about populating that migration data so EF knows the db is up to date?

Comment: I would think deleting your migration history could help

Comment: All the existing migrations? I've got other instances of the database that contain data. So I can't delete migrations as I won't be able to bring it inline

Comment: Do you have other databases that are not up to date? Or are they all stable/equivalent? Is there any reason to keep the update history in the solution?

Comment: Have stable databases that I'll be updating when I push new code yes.

Comment: To refine my question: what purpose do the old history files serve?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to ask, how did you go about resolving the issue you had? The idea of migrations is that you can go backwards and forwards through them, allowing you to revert any changes.

That said, you are where you are. In this instance I would have to agree with @sq33G and remove the existing migrations, and fix your current database. As you haven't provided a comprehensive account of your problem I would suggest that data elsewhere could be imported into your current database if required with SQL queries.